# Wait for GET request to have certain variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, asynchronous, get

I'm using POST to submit jobs remotely from my application.  The POST request returns a job ID that I can use a GET request to check the status of.

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8090/jobs/'+id).then(function successCallback(results) { 
    jobResults = results; 
}
```

Only problem is I would like to assign the variable after the job is done, and not right when it just started.  Is there a way to do that?

If it is done, the results look like this:

```
{
  "duration": "0.171 secs",
  "classPath": "spark.jobserver.WordCountExample",
  "startTime": "2017-02-17T22:47:49.291Z",
  "context": "c4c62dd3-spark.jobserver.WordCountExample",
  "result": {
    "word1": 1,
    "word2": 3
  },
  "status": "FINISHED",
  "jobId": "994569f9-b6a5-40d3-a4b3-f281276c6716"
}
```

The only difference aside from the status message if it's not done is that the "result" variable is not there.

Comment: Where do you want to use that variable? in the view?

Comment: @digit yes I was hoping to update it on the frontend

Comment: With the AngularJS $http service the code would need to poll the server every second or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is you are trying to find a solution in the wrong place. What i see is that your job is being processed in the backend, so you want to update it in the frontend but you have not the information needed to do that. 
So you will have to wirte a process that check the job status for assign the variable when you want to doi it, in this case when the job is finished. You can do it with setInterval for example.

```
var jobs = [];
setInterval(function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < jobs.lenght; i++) {
    checkJobStatus();
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try the below get url.
Consider you get jobId from post request.

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8090/jobs/:id',{id : jobId}).then(function successCallback(results) { 
    jobResults = results; 
}
```